# Why do bits of paper stick to the CRT television screen?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics

Once i switched on my television and i noticed that bits of paper and pieces of string stick to it. I decided to conduct my own experiment and bought a headphone jack near the screen and there was a visible spark on the jack . Can anyone explain this phenomenon.

Answer (score -1):

Because the electrons after be scaning to the screen are still stuck in the glass and make the capacitor effect,the glass surface is the electrode plate,the air as a dialectric and you are a final electrode so electrons would transfer over your body.